# CSRF / ASP.NET Web Forms, Is "Double Submission" considered an issue?

Tags: vb.net, csrf

With a great help of StafOverflow community, I was able to implement following method in my master page for 100s of web forms, this solution creates unique anti-forgery key and authenticated user info to validate the submission.
http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf

However I am curious to know if following "double submission" scenario is considered vulnerability or not.

**Before the above solution**, I was able to do following,
I was able to use LINK #2 and submit forgery request at all times.

- LINK #1. http://mycompanydomain/TestAccount.aspx
- LINK #2. C:\csrf_TestAccount.html

**After the solution**, LINK #2 will fail if I open new browser(To make sure, I've updated __EVENTVALIDATION & __VIEWSTATE in LINK#2). **BUT** I am still able to submit forgery request using LINK #2 under "new tab"(not new session).

So my question is, is this still considered vulnerability?

Following is what has been implemented.

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        setAntiForgeryKey()
        AddHandler Page.PreLoad, AddressOf master_Page_PreLoad
.
.
.
End Sub

Protected Sub setAntiForgeryKey()
    Dim requestCookie = Request.Cookies(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
    Dim requestCookieGuidValue As New Guid

    If requestCookie IsNot Nothing AndAlso Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, requestCookieGuidValue) Then
        _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value

        Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue
    Else
        _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
        Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue
        Dim responseCookie = New HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey) With { _
            .HttpOnly = True, _
            .Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue _
        }
        If (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL And Request.IsSecureConnection) Then responseCookie.Secure = True
        Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie)
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub master_Page_PreLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ViewState(AntiXsrfTokenKey) = Page.ViewStateUserKey
        ViewState(AntiXsrfUserNameKey) = UserID
    Else
        If (CType(ViewState(AntiXsrfTokenKey), String) <> _antiXsrfTokenValue) Or _
            (CType(ViewState(AntiXsrfUserNameKey), String) <> UserID) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're manually updating the `__viewstate` value in Link #2 then you are adding information that an attacker won't have access to - therefore your test is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm.. all I did was, click viewsource and grabbed the __viewstate.

Comment: An attacker will not be able to see the `__viewstate` as they are on their own computer, not the victim's.

Comment: The idea is to have a different CSRF token per user session. If the token from one session works on another then your CSRF protection is useless.

Comment: Your are correct. I think my testing was incorrect and is already protected as it also checks the user's authenticity.

My requirement is also including hacker is someone who has authorized access to the system. So, this malicious user would have same access as I would, and goes to webforms and forge the request for later use. So, the malicious user would have access to VIEWSTATE, however, if I make the viewstate using userid, it would fail anyway.